# How to charge gratuity at a later stage to a paypal credit card payment using the same transaction?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm developing an e-commerce website using PHP and integrating paypal for processing the credit card payments.
I found APIs in PHP that are used to make payments and capture transaction id but none of these discussed about adding adjustments to the amount that is captured. 
My use cases include:
Adding tip later
Adding time extension adjustments
Returning only portion of the amount if order gets cancelled
and few more of similar kind

May anyone tell me how this kind of a task is handled with paypal and also is there any API that will provide this functionality as well?

Comment: This isn't possible with paypal, it must be part of the original transaction submitted to them. If you try to order food via grubhub and pay with paypal, you'll see that they ask for the tip upfront (before redirect to paypal) for this very reason. Paypal is not like a traditional credit card merchant where you can auth for one amount and settle for a different amount after the fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References Transactions would work fine to charge a separate transaction for the tip, but then the customers would see two separate charges on their credit card and you'll probably get lots of questions and confused people wondering why their card was hit twice.  As obvious as it seems, I've been there.

The best way to handle it would be to run an Authorization when you first run the card.  Authorize it for something like 50% above the ticket total, or whatever you think it would take to cover the final total including a tip for that order.

If the order is canceled for any reason you simply Void the authorization.  If you're ready to actually process the funds with a final total including tip, then you can Capture the amount that you need up to the amount that you originally authorized.  I believe you may even be able to capture up to 10% more than the original authorization, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

The thing you would need to be careful about is authorizing a card for some large amount and then not voiding or capturing shortly after.  The authorization is only guaranteed for 3 days.  You can run a re-authorization and get an additional 3 days if you need to.

If the order gets canceled and you don't void it then you'll get complaints that a large amount is "charged" on their account.  It looks like a charge until it clears back or is voided.  If you don't void it then it can take up to 29 days for them to get access to those funds on their account again, so you want to avoid those types of complaints too.

You would need Payments Pro to handle credit cards directly for that sort of a system.  Depending on which version of Pro they put you on you'll use either the PayFlow API, or you'll use variations of DoDirectPayment, DoVoid, DoCapture, DoReauthorization.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The business is a renting service so the customer is charged extra if they exceed usage time than requesting time as well and also the cost of the product if they mishandle it. So there are several cases involved and not just tip in processing another payment using the existing transaction id. So I'm not sure that authorizing and voiding would work in this case.
Also I wanted to know whether there's any upper limit with the amount which is processed after the first payment.
Thanks..

Comment: The procedure I outlined would handle any original charges that need to be made.  Then you could indeed use reference transactions to automatically process future payments as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Reference transactions would work for what you are trying to do. Reference transactions allows you to reference a previous transaction to run another transaction on that information at a later date. Here is a link to more information on reference transactions. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look into it. Please share any code snippets or any live example if you come across.